# Android Layout for Buttons with Images

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I am trying to create an android layout that uses about 1/3 of the screen for a App Title.  And then for the other 2/3 it has 6 evenly spaced out buttons in rows of 2, in 3 columns.  In each button will contain text and an image that could potentially vary in size.  I have been reading a lot and have yet to come up with a perfect way to to this.  I have an example that mostly works except a few of my buttons are different sizes and so this does not work (buttons are different sizes).  Plus i have no idea if it will work with phones of different sizes.  Anyway, if anyone could take a look at this xml layout and maybe suggest a better way.  Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget30"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/green6"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/widget31"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Title Will Go Here"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/green6"
                android:textSize="35sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" 
                android:shadowColor="@color/black"
                android:shadowDx="0"
                android:shadowDy="0"
                android:shadowRadius="1"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/search"
                    android:text="Search by Food"
                    android:textColor="@color/green6"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/search2"
                    android:text="Search by Substitute"
                    android:textColor="@color/green6"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/browse"
                    android:text="Browse by Category"
                    android:textColor="@color/green6"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/award"
                    android:text="Most Popular"
                    android:textColor="@color/green6"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/share"
                    android:text="Sync with Online Database"
                    android:textColor="@color/green6"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout6"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/plus"
                    android:text="Submit New Food Substitute"
                    android:textColor="@color/green6"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Chinese proverb: **one picture worth ten thousand words.**

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a top-level LinearLayout and specify layout_weight of 1 for the app title.  Then I'd use a [DashboardLayout](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/ui/widget/DashboardLayout.java) with a layout_weight of 2 for the 2x3 grid of ImageButtons.

DashboardLayout was used in the Google I/O 2011 app, aka IOSched, available at http://code.google.com/p/iosched/ .  I'd recommend downloading and browsing that code for some examples of how that layout works.  Note that you'll have to copy that one DashboardLayout.java file to your project.

You could make this even simpler if you're using an ActionBar - just specify the title for your Activity in the AndroidManifest.xml and then set the DashboardLayout at the root of your layout.  The app title won't be anywhere near 1/3rd, but it will probably fit in better with Honeycomb/ICS apps.

Comment: This looks very interesting.  Why have I not heard about the dashboard layout until now? I will try it out later today or tomorrow and I will get back to this thread and tell you all if it worked.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will do what I need it to.  Appreciate your help.  Is there a place that lists all the new Android layouts like this dashboard layout?

Comment: You might want to look at Android UI Patterns.  The [Smartphone UI Patterns](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/p/android-ui-pattern-collection.html) collection is probably what you're looking for.